# SSIS - Deploying package to file system

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I've had to edit an already deployed package on a SSIS server on my computer. I now wish to deploy this package back to this server which is located in (from SQL Server Management Studio) `serverName > Stored Packages > File System > packageName`.

However, I don't know how to do so, and I've been trying to follow this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140117(v=sql.105).aspx, under the "To deploy packages to file system" section but to no avail.

I remoted in to the server but I can't find this "deployment folder" in order to run the manifest file. Can anyone help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: How do you run your packages in the server? Through a SQL agent job? Open the job, confirm that it is running from the file system (not msdb) and check the path to the .dtsx file that it's running. Now just copy your .dtsx file over that (after you back up the existing file). This is unless you need to change the path to configurations before deployment.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid It's through an agent job and it's definitely a file system, however, I've managed to fix my problem so I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to fix my problem as all I had to do was build the package on Visual Studio BIDS, by right clicking the project on the Solution Explorer on the right hand side and selecting `Properties`. I then clicked on `Deployment Utility` on the pop-up window and set the `CreateDeploymentUtility` to `True`. I then clicked OK.

I then right clicked on the project in the Solution Explorer again and clicked on `Build` in the pop-up drop-down menu.

After it was successfully built, I logged in to the Integration Services server on SQL Server Management Studio, and then navigated to `Stored Packages > File System` in the Object Explorer and right clicked on `File System` and clicked `Import Package`.

In the pop-up window I selected `File System` in the Package location field, and browsed and selected the built package located in the my `project folder\bin\Deployment`. I left the Package name field as the same as the original package and then overwrote the original package after clicking OK in the window.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting a detailed answer